# Elasticsearch - how to get the lowest price for a given date range

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm working on a hotel booking application, and need to display a low-price calendar.

I have created a Price class like this:

```
public class Price
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And now would like to get the lowest prices for a given city.
I tried something like this:

```
var result = client.Search<Price>(s => s
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(1000)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                m => m.Term(t => t.CityId, cityId),
                m => m.DateRange(r => r.Field(rf => rf.Date).GreaterThanOrEquals(startDate).LessThanOrEquals(endDate))))));
```

The problem is, if there are several hotels in the city, I will get more than one price for each day.

Here's an example:

```
Id = 1
CityId = 1
HotelId = 1
Value = 100
Date = 2017-01-25

Id = 2
CityId = 1
HotelId = 2
Value = 200
Date = 2017-01-25

Id = 3
CityId = 1
HotelId = 1
Value = 400
Date = 2017-01-26

Id = 4
CityId = 1
HotelId = 2
Value = 300
Date = 2017-01-26
```

If I send the following request:

```
cityId = 1
startDate = 2017-01-25
endDate = 2017-01-26
```

My query will return documents 1, 2, 3 and 4.
But I would like to return only documents 1 and 4.
(100 is the lowest price on 2017-01-25, and 300 is the lowest price on 2017-01-26)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using aggregations, specifically the min aggregation?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/min-aggregation.html

Comment: I tried to add .Aggregations(a => a.Min("min_price", ma => ma.Field(p => p.Value))) , but this gives me only one aggreagation (total lowest price). I need the lowest price per day, not the lowest price for the whole result set.

Comment: You need to use a DateHistogram aggregation with a Min sub-aggregation and you'll have what you expect for each day.

Answer (score 0):

i don't carry much working knowledge of nest and it syntax. So i will try to give you native ES query and you can later work it out on nest.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "Date",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_per_day": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "Value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "cityId": {
                        "value": 2
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "Date": {
                        "gte": 10,
                        "lte": 20
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Add a date-histogram with one day interval and furthur evaluate aggregation for minimum on Value field.

Thanks